# What means execute S_2, S_3 and S_4: COMMIT in Postgresql logs?

Tags: postgresql, database-internals

I'd noticed different commit types in Postgres log:

```
2019-12-20 12:00:00  [99999]: [12-1] host=...,user=...,db=... LOG:  duration: 1000.000 ms execute S_2: COMMIT
2019-12-20 12:00:00  [99999]: [12-1] host=...,user=...,db=... LOG:  duration: 1000.000 ms execute S_3: COMMIT
2019-12-20 12:00:00  [99999]: [12-1] host=...,user=...,db=... LOG:  duration: 1000.000 ms execute S_4: COMMIT
```

Note: I changed some information to omit sensitive data.

**What can I conclude when I see these different types of commit in the log?**

Comment: here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715164/understanding-log-execute-s-1-begin-in-postgresql) from a few years ago

Comment: @zsheep thanks, but It's not clear yet. These entries are created by connection drivers or Postgres internals? And what I can infer with them?